Python Paramiko method paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect only receives files via key_filename, is there a way to pass a string variable?
Python's package Paramiko has the moehtod paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect to connect. It receives the private key as a file with the parameter key_filename.
ssh.connect(key_filename=key_filename)
For security purpouses I'm not having a file with my private key in my repository, then I'm using it as a secret variable:
key_filename = os.getenv("go")
but when I retreive the secret it returns as string, is there a was to pass the pk as a string variable and not a path to paramiko?
